# Can I use GoTo for a UI:?

Tags: vbscript

I'm currently making a User Interface for this package I'm making and I'm trying to make a "Back" Choice. To return to the previous thing.

```
START:
Input = Inputbox("Choose One Of The Options!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Information" & vbNewLine & "Cool" & vbNewLine & "Hacks", "Solus")
If Input = "Information" Then
Input1 = Inputbox("Here's The Information!" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & "Information" & vbNewLine & "Speech" & vbNewLine & "Back", "Information")
If Input1 = "Information" Then
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Roland\Desktop\Solus\Information\Info.txt"
ElseIf Input = "Speech" Then
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.Run "C:\Users\Roland\Desktop\Solus\Information\Speech.vbs"
ElseIf Input = "Back" Then
GoTo START
```

So I want it that if they Enter "Back" Into the InputBox it will go back to the beginning of the script. If anyone knows of a way to do this I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: You are talking about UI, why not it to be GUI with HTA?

Answer (score 1):

VBScript doesn't `go to`, you need a loop and exit(s). As in:

```
Do
  WScript.StdOut.Write "A or B or Q to quit > "
  Select Case WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
    Case "A"
      WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "A"
      Exit Do
    Case "B"
      WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "B"
      Exit Do
    Case "Q"
      WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Q"
      Exit Do
    Case Else
      WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Bad Input"
    End Select
Loop
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Done"
```

Output:

```
cscript 7625740.vbs
A or B or Q to quit > A
A
Done

cscript 7625740.vbs
A or B or Q to quit > C
Bad Input
A or B or Q to quit > Q
Q
Done
```